# No categories in the layered navigation

Tags: magento2, category, layered-navigation

I stuck with a problem that some of the categories won't show in the layered navigation. An anchor is enabled, re-indexation and cache clearing made many times, changed the theme to default Luma. Strange that 3 of them are showing. I thought maybe problem with the URL rewrite because I made product imports. Truncated tables and also didn't help. Magento version is 2.3.2
[image: view of categories filter]
[image: view of missed category in the layered navigation]

Comment: maybe it uses parent category config. you can check it.

Comment: "Use Parent Category Settings" set to "No" for all categories. Also, I tried to enable the option "Flat category", then re-indexation and cache flush - no working.

Answer (score 0):

Products were assigned to the parent category "Produktai" and child category "Baldai" when I unassigned them from the parent category, then the category appeared in the layered navigation.